# Scrollbar handling scroll event in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form which looks like this.

Form1 has two panels:

- the bottom panel (yellow)
- the top panel, which is himself composed by two panels:

  - the left panel (red)
  - the right panel (green)

[image]

As the image shows, the top panel, exceeds form1's height, so I would like to use a scrollbar. I have several problems:

a) Setting auto-scroll to true in the top panel does not work.

b) If I put a button on the top panel whose location exceeds form1's height, then it scrolls, but NOT if I put it in any of its subpanels (red or green)

c) Instead of setting auto-scroll to true in the top panel, I could create my own scrollbar, but I just couldn't find a simple example handling the scroll event that moves the panel so that the view port changes as desired.

How could I properly add a scrollbar with the desired behaviour?

Comment: Where do you want to have scrollbar, on form or on Yellow panel?

Comment: @vendettamit I would like a vertical scroll bar in the 'top' panel which is composed by the red and green panels

Comment: Those three panels look like they should all be Docked — Bottom, Left and Filled.  Set the AutoScrollMinSize for the panel you want the scrollbar to show up in.

Comment: @de3 can you open the `Document Outline` windows in VS and add the screenshot of hierarchy of your panels on form?

Comment: AutoScroll has no effect because the panel doesn't have any child controls that need a scrollbar to be fully visible.  Which begs the question why you want a scrollbar.  Setting the panel's AutoScrollMinSize is another way to force a scrollbar.  Then again, maybe you are actually looking for the form's AutoScroll property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LarsTech and Hans Passant suggested, AutoScrollMinSize worked, so a and b questions were solved.

Regarding question C, I thought there was a way to create a scrollbar so that it behaves like I guess 99% of scrollbars should behave (just to move a desired panel). Finally, I coded that logic myself.

I added a Scrollbar1 as a control of the basic form. *initialPanelY* is catched on the constructor.

This is the code that responds to the scroll event. I just move the panel panelRest2's Y location depending on the scrollbar value

```
using System;
 .
 .
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormMyTests
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    int initialPanelY;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initialPanelY = this.panelRest2.Location.Y;
    }

    private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object  sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        int v = (sender as VScrollBar).Value; //between 1 and 100
        int hiddenPanelHeight = this.panelRest2.Size.Height - this.Size.Height;
        float moveY = (float)hiddenPanelHeight * ((float)v / 100);
        int newY = initialPanelY - (int)moveY;
        this.panelRest2.Location = new Point(this.panelRest2.Location.X, newY);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show what's setting up vScrollBar1_Scroll.  Where do you add that event handler?